# Python Selenium _ Interacting with an "li" element in an iframe

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a "li" element on the interactive chart from this link: https://api.gdeltproject.org/api/v2/summary/summary?d=web&t=compare&k1=Asasd&k2=asd&ts=full&stm=yes&c=1

The element is within an iframe, so I switched over to the frame. But, Selenium still cannot find the element even when searching by xpath. I want to have my code click the "Save Data as CSV" link.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to frame, like below and then use explicit waits like below to click on **Save Data As CSV**:

The  below code do it :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://api.gdeltproject.org/api/v2/summary/summary?d=web&t=compare&k1=Asasd&k2=asd&ts=full&stm=yes&c=1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "timelinemerge")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='View chart menu']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Save Data As CSV']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```